# Как изменить число при делении по модулю для сохранения результата при изменении делителя?

Tags: математика

Есть формула:

```
RESULT = (CONST + var) % MOD
```

`RESULT` - целое число, >= 0

`CONST`, `var`, `MOD` - целые числа, > 0

Вопрос:

Как изменится `var`, если:

- `MOD` увеличить на 1
- `MOD` уменьшить на 1

При этом `RESULT` и `CONST` не должны измениться.

Не брутфорсом.

Comment: Если по условию mod > 0 и =1, то mod-1 = 0, тогда решения не будет. Это я так, к слову) Это, кстати, может быть одним из решений

Comment: а точно больше нет никаких ограничений?

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение. Исходное уравнение

```
RESULT = (CONST + var) % MOD
```

Пусть, `NEWMOD` - увеличенный или уменьшенный `MOD`.

```
var = NEWMOD - (CONST - RESULT) % NEWMOD
```

#### На примерах.

На исходном примере.

```
(25 + 15) % 16 = 8
```

- `CONST = 25`
- `var = 15`
- `MOD = 16`
- `RESULT = 8`

Увеличиваем:

```
NEWMOD = MOD + 1 = 17

var = 17 - (25 - 8) % 17 = 17 - 0 = 17

(25 + 17) % 17 = 8
```

Уменьшаем:

```
NEWMOD = MOD - 1 = 15

var = 15 - (25 - 8) % 15 = 15 - 2 = 13

(25 + 13) % 15 = 8
```

---

**UPD:** что касается доказательства.

Перенесём результат на другую часть равенства или, проще сказать, уменьшим обе части на значение результата.

Т.к. в правой части у нас не деление, а остаток от него, то это допустимо.

```
CONST + var >= RESULT
```

, т.к. `RESULT` это остаток от деления

```
(25 - 8 + var) % 16 = 0 => (17 + var) % 16 = 0
```

Другими словами (частный случай):

```
17 + var = 16 => var = 16 - 17 = -1

(25 + (-1)) % 16 = 8
```

Нужно сказать, что ответ тут не один. Ответом будут числа с интервалом в значение модуля.

В данном случае: -1, 15, 31, 47 и т.д.

Comment: А доказательство?

Comment: @cronfy  `(N-(C-R)%N+C)%N = 0 - C+R+C = R`

Comment: доказательство добавил в ответ